# MP bar chart android error

Tags: android, graph, charts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEAum.png)I am using MP bar chart in my project. I copy paste the code from one tutorial. The code in that tutorial is working absolutely fine but giving an error in my project.

```
    BarChart barChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.barchart);

    ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    entries.add(new BarEntry(8f, 0));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(2f, 1));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(5f, 2));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(20f, 3));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(15f, 4));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(19f, 5));

    BarDataSet bardataset = new BarDataSet(entries, "Cells");

    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
        labels.add("2016");
        labels.add("2015");
        labels.add("2014");
        labels.add("2013");
        labels.add("2012");
        labels.add("2011");

    //error on this line because of string arraylist 
    //BarData data = new BarData(labels, bardataset);
    barChart.setData(data); // set the data and list of lables into chart

    barChart.setDescription("Set Bar Chart Description"); // set the description

    bardataset.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

    barChart.animateY(5000);
```

//XML file

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
            android:id="@+id/barchart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <!--com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
            android:id="@+id/graph"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dip" /-->

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please share your error log.

Comment: Error is not on run time, I am not able to run, red color line below

Comment: set this barChart.setData(bardataset); instead of barChart.setData(data);

Comment: You can not pass the string arraylist to barChart.setData();

Comment: But the one in tutorial is passing ArrayList and app is running successfully and many example are also doing that

Comment: Not able to set barChart.setData(bardataset)

Comment: As per the documentation it is clearly said that you have to pass DataSet to set data

Comment: Sorry you need to Pass BarData to barchar.setData(bardata). For this you need to create a BarData.

Comment: See my answer bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simple tutorial. You get some idea from this.

```
 ArrayList<BarEntry> bargroup1 = new ArrayList<>();
    bargroup1.add(new BarEntry(8f,0));
    bargroup1.add(new BarEntry(2f,1));
    bargroup1.add(new BarEntry(5f,2));
    bargroup1.add(new BarEntry(20f,3));
    bargroup1.add(new BarEntry(15f,4));
    bargroup1.add(new BarEntry(19f,5));

BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(bargroup1, "Group 1");
barDataSet1.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    labels.add("2016");
    labels.add("2015");
    labels.add("2014");
    labels.add("2013");
    labels.add("2012");
    labels.add("2011");

ArrayList<BarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
    dataSets.add(barDataSet1);

BarData data = new BarData(labels, dataSets); 
barChart.setData(data);
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if you found useful. So other can use this. :)

Comment: Not able to solve it , your code is also not working, please see image I have attached with the post

Comment: I think the problem is with your mpAndroidChartVersion. Which version you are using?

Comment: compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'

Comment: try this one it will not giving the error compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.0-beta1'